# Oracle APEX execute Procedure/Function

Tags: oracle-apex

I want to write a custom login and for that I want to use a procedure/function to create and login the user (to hash the password)

My current database setup looks like this (From this site: https://oracle-base.com/articles/9i/storing-passwords-in-the-database-9i):

```
CREATE TABLE app_users (
  id        NUMBER(10)    NOT NULL,
  username  VARCHAR2(30)  NOT NULL,
  password  VARCHAR2(40)  NOT NULL
)
/

ALTER TABLE app_users ADD (
  CONSTRAINT app_users_pk PRIMARY KEY (id)
)
/

ALTER TABLE app_users ADD (
  CONSTRAINT app_users_uk UNIQUE (username)
)
/

CREATE SEQUENCE app_users_seq
/
```

My current PLSQL Package definition looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE app_user_security AS

  FUNCTION get_hash (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                     p_password  IN  VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2;

  PROCEDURE add_user (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                      p_password  IN  VARCHAR2);

  PROCEDURE change_password (p_username      IN  VARCHAR2,
                             p_old_password  IN  VARCHAR2,
                             p_new_password  IN  VARCHAR2);

  PROCEDURE valid_user (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                        p_password  IN  VARCHAR2);

  FUNCTION valid_user (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                       p_password  IN  VARCHAR2)
    RETURN BOOLEAN;

END;
/
```

And the package itself looks like this:

```
CREATE OR REPLACE PACKAGE BODY app_user_security AS

  FUNCTION get_hash (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                     p_password  IN  VARCHAR2)
    RETURN VARCHAR2 AS
    l_salt VARCHAR2(30) := 'PutYourSaltHere';
  BEGIN
    -- Pre Oracle 10g
    RETURN DBMS_OBFUSCATION_TOOLKIT.MD5(
      input_string => UPPER(p_username) || l_salt || UPPER(p_password));

    -- Oracle 10g+ : Requires EXECUTE on DBMS_CRYPTO
    --RETURN DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH(UTL_RAW.CAST_TO_RAW(UPPER(p_username) || l_salt || UPPER(p_password)),DBMS_CRYPTO.HASH_SH1);
  END;

  PROCEDURE add_user (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                      p_password  IN  VARCHAR2) AS
  BEGIN
    INSERT INTO app_users (
      id,
      username,
      password
    )
    VALUES (
      app_users_seq.NEXTVAL,
      UPPER(p_username),
      get_hash(p_username, p_password)
    );

    COMMIT;
  END;

  PROCEDURE change_password (p_username      IN  VARCHAR2,
                             p_old_password  IN  VARCHAR2,
                             p_new_password  IN  VARCHAR2) AS
    v_rowid  ROWID;
  BEGIN
    SELECT rowid
    INTO   v_rowid
    FROM   app_users
    WHERE  username = UPPER(p_username)
    AND    password = get_hash(p_username, p_old_password)
    FOR UPDATE;

    UPDATE app_users
    SET    password = get_hash(p_username, p_new_password)
    WHERE  rowid    = v_rowid;

    COMMIT;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Invalid username/password.');
  END;

  PROCEDURE valid_user (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                        p_password  IN  VARCHAR2) AS
    v_dummy  VARCHAR2(1);
  BEGIN
    SELECT '1'
    INTO   v_dummy
    FROM   app_users
    WHERE  username = UPPER(p_username)
    AND    password = get_hash(p_username, p_password);
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN NO_DATA_FOUND THEN
      RAISE_APPLICATION_ERROR(-20000, 'Invalid username/password.');
  END;

  FUNCTION valid_user (p_username  IN  VARCHAR2,
                       p_password  IN  VARCHAR2) 
    RETURN BOOLEAN AS
  BEGIN
    valid_user(p_username, p_password);
    RETURN TRUE;
  EXCEPTION
    WHEN OTHERS THEN
      RETURN FALSE;
  END;

END;
/
```

I can call it like this in the CMD:

```
exec app_user_security.add_user('admin','admin');
```

But if I want to create a user in APEX > SQL Workshop > SQL Commands, it just tells me

> ORA-00900: invalid SQL statement

Why is that so and how can I fix this? I want to use this login later on a application with a custom login scheme so it would be nice if there were some users in there.

Comment: Are you using MS SQL Server or Oracle? Don't tag products not involved.

Comment: @jarlh oracle - it told me to use it xD  idk i randomly clicked on the tags because who reads them anyways?

Comment: We all read them to find (or avoid). Skip all tags if you find them redundant...

Comment: @jarlh updated the tags. im sorry - using stackoverflow the second time right now (as a question creator)

Comment: Much better! Remember that an answer for SQL Server may or may not be suitable for Oracle. Correct tagging will give you the best quality anwers - fastest! (And not waste other users' time writing answers for an unused product.)

Answer (score 0, accepted):

Please try to run below code under APEX > SQL Workshop > SQL Commands

```
 BEGIN

  app_user_security.add_user('admin','admin');

 END;
```

To know more about sql command under Sql workshop please check below link
https://docs.oracle.com/cd/E37097_01/doc.42/e35128/GUID-AF7DD819-A3E4-4027-84B7-4AEAD16314B7.htm#AEUTL219

Hope this will help you!